# Require authorization with conditions require_auth(name1 OR name2)

Tags: smart-contract, authorization

Is there any possibility to implement conditional `require_auth(<condition>)` or what is a good practice to make contract accept invocations from a set of predetermined accounts? Is there any analogue of solidity's `msg.sender` in EOS?

It seems that the documentation for [require_auth2](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/reference#require_auth2) is missing.

Example: I need the contract to require authorization from account `walletxxxxxx` OR `walletzzzzzz`.

```cpp
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

class [[eosio::contract("tmp")]] tmp : public eosio::contract {

public:
  using contract::contract;

  tmp(name receiver, name code,  datastream<const char*> ds): contract(receiver, code, ds) {}

  // Bad practice of multiauth implementation.
  [[eosio::action]]
  void multiauth(name user) {

    // Allow only `walletxxxxxx` OR `walletzzzzzz`
    // to call this function.

    if (user == name("walletxxxxxx"))
    {
      require_auth(name("walletxxxxxx"));
    }
    else if (user == name("walletzzzzzz"))
    {
      require_auth(name("walletzzzzzz"));
    }
    else
    {
      require_auth(name(get_self()));
    }

    // DO SOMETHING
  }

private:

};

EOSIO_DISPATCH( tmp, (multiauth) )
```

Honestly, the above contract can solve my problem, but it does not look like a good practice. I'm looking for any relevant documentation in regards to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The above case works if you do it like the following:

```
void multiauth(name user) {

   if (user == name("walletxxxxxx") || user == name("walletzzzzzz"))
   {
     require_auth(user);
   }
   else
   {
     require_auth(_self);
   }
}
```

But that's definitely not state of the art to grant permissions for execution of actions to specific accounts on eosio.

The name 'multiauth' itself says **permissions should be granted to multiple users**, a feature other blockchains lack of. And **eosio's** solution is the **inbuild permission system**.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
check(has_auth(name1) || has_auth(name2));
```

Comment: check(has_auth(name1) || has_auth(name2), "Invalid user");